# Close window through Capybara

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am trying to launch the browser for the capybara automation.  The browser is auto populating a "Error window" (non-browser window).

I need to "close/click ok" on the window to open the browser. I tried to handle this popup with the "AutoIT" executable file.  When i run the AutoIT file manually, the executable file handles it successfully.

I am not able to execute through the capybara script.  The code is as below

```
ses = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
IO.popen('c:\ruby\handler.exe') #- Tried this step to execute AutoIT .exe file before visit url step.
```

No luck here.  The popup appears only when referencing with the object.

```
ses.execute_script "window.close()"  #- Tried this step to close the window with  the ses object. no luck in this too.

ses.visit "https://google.com"
```

Is there a way to close the window programmatically?

Comment: Are you sure there is indeed an "error window" opened in Capybara tests? Where does it come from? Can you [make a screenshot](http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2012/01/screenshots-with-capybara-selenium/) during a running capybara session and post it here? In general, you should e.g. be able to define a separate [browser profile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12752763/1544012) to use in capybara sessions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply BoraMa !  the error is from chrome browser . The window message is "Failed to load Extension" . Loading of unpacked extensions are disabled by administrator. I am trying to close this window.

Comment: Jennifer, I am trying to say that a better approach might be to get rid of the error window altogether if you create a browser profile that does not try to load the prohibited extensions at all. Because I doubt that closing a browser error message is possible from javascript which is about all that capybara has access to.

Comment: Can you please suggest which profile option to disable load extensions. Capybara.register_driver :selenium do|app|
   profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Profile.new
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome,  :detach => :unspecified) 
end

Comment: Have a look at my answer below, I think there is a way to pass an option to disable all extensions for the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you should be able to **register a custom selenium driver** using the Chrome browser and specify the command-line option to disable all extensions, with the following driver registry code:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, 
                                      :switches => %w[--disable-extensions])
end

ses = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
...
```

I put this together using information [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings#command-line-switches) and the list of available command line options [here](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) (I did not test this myself though).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches to a popup error like that:

1) The easiest one is to do your approach - execute an autoit script before calling capybara to visit the site that results in the error popping up. You should ensure that the autoit script you are executing waits for the window to appear before trying to close it (see: https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinWait.htm for reference).

2) You could execute another ruby script/thread (keep in mind threading in ruby is a bit complicated) that would execute the autoit script in the background (in a loop) and wait for a succesfull response.

3) You could try to disable whatever is causing the error to pop up in your browser.

I will be able to provide some code following approaches 1 and 2 in a few hours if you will still have problems solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Failed to load Extension. Loading of unpacked extensions are disabled by administrator.` indicates that your system was set-up to disable extensions with Chrome. So even if you manage to close it, you probably won't be able to automate Chrome with Selenium since it needs to start Chrome with the driver as an extension.

Your best chance to make it work is probably to disable the restriction or to add the extension to the white list.

Here is a link about this issue:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=639